# Print a array of strings nicely in C

Tags: c, formatting, printf, posix

I am working with C printing the array of strings which is so huge
Ex:

```
static const char * const fruits[] =
{   
"apple",
"banana",
"pine apple",
"two apple",
"two banana",
"two  pine apple",
"three apple",
"three banana",
"three pine apple"
};
```

I am trying to iterate and print the values of array 3 in a row

```
void printNames(){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 10 ; i++){
            if(i%3== 0){
                printf("\n");
            }
            printf("%s: %d | ",fruits[i],i);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

This gives me the output:

```
apple:0 | banana :1 | pine apple:2 |
two apple:3 | two banana :4 | two  pine apple:5 |
three apple:6 |three banana :7 | three pine apple:8 |
```

I am trying to achieve something like this:

```
apple:0       | banana :1       | pine apple:2       |
two apple:3   | two banana :4   | two  pine apple:5  |
three apple:6 | three banana :7 | three pine apple:8 |
```

Any suggestions and help is appreciated
Thanks.

Comment: First loop through the array to figure required width of each column. Then loop again, this time adding required padding to each output to make all entries in each column the same width.

Comment: How do we know how much padding is required for each element in an array?

Comment: why are you missing `,` between `"pine apple"` and `"two apple",` and another place also,  that will cause errors in output

Comment: hi @IrAM sorry, it was an example of my actual question. edited it. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @user3121023 that solution works, Is there an efficient way to get that value 20?
For example, if there is one value that is greater than 25 characters. it would be 20-25 which results in negative. Is there something that we can use to limit that to print only 20 char even though it's 25 char and doesn't use any  padding in that case?

Comment: Thank you so much @user3121023. Just one last question, can we make this (20 - strlen ( fruits[i])) return 0 - when the length of the fruit is >20?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This iterates through `fruits` and assigns an `overall` width and a `column` width based on `strlen` and the number of digits. There is also a `MAX` of twenty for the length of a string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define COLS 3
#define MAX 20

static const char * const separator = " | ";
static const char * const fruits[] = {
    "apple",
    "banana",
    "pine apple",
    "two apple",
    "two banana",
    "two  pine apple",
    "three apple",
    "three banana",
    "three pine apple",
    "four abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
    "four 0123456789",
    "four pine apple",
    NULL
};

int main ( void) {
    int i;
    int overall = 0;
    int column[COLS] = { 0};

    for ( i = 0; fruits[i]; i++){//fruits[i] is not NULL
        int digits = 0;
        int temp = i;
        while ( temp) {
            ++digits;
            temp /= 10;
        }

        temp = strlen ( fruits[i]);
        if ( temp > MAX) {
            temp = MAX;
        }
        temp += digits;
        if ( overall < temp) {
            overall = temp;
        }
        if ( column[i % COLS] < temp) {
            column[i % COLS] = temp;
        }
    }
    //use overall width
    for ( i = 0; fruits[i]; i++){
        if ( i % COLS == 0){
            printf ( "\n");
        }
        else {
            printf ( "%s", separator);
        }
        int len = strlen ( fruits[i]);
        if ( len >= MAX) {
            len = MAX;
        }
        int width = overall - len;
        printf ( "%.*s: %-*d", MAX, fruits[i], width, i);
    }
    printf ( "\n");
    //use column width
    for ( i = 0; fruits[i]; i++){
        if ( i % COLS == 0){
            printf ( "\n");
        }
        else {
            printf ( "%s", separator);
        }
        int len = strlen ( fruits[i]);
        if ( len >= MAX) {
            len = MAX;
        }
        int width = column[i % COLS] - len;
        printf ( "%.*s: %-*d", MAX, fruits[i], width, i);
    }
    printf ( "\n");
}
```